# Spark Exception while writing a Dataframe to an External Partitioned Hive Table using Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am running a spark job on multinode cluster and trying to insert(append) a dataframe to an external Hive Table which is partitioned by 2 columns- date and hr.

```
dataframe.write().insertInto(hiveTable);
```

Hive table structure is as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `database.hiveTable`(
  `col1` string,
  `col2` string,
  `col3_json` string,
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `dt` string,
  `hr` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/data/hdfs/tmp/test';
```

Note: col3_json column will have data in json string like:

```
{"group":[{"action":"Change","gid":"111","isId":"Y"},{"action":"Add","gid":"111","isId":"Y"},{"action":"Delete","gid":"111","isId":"N"}]}
```

The data is getting successfully inserted when the table is not partitioned.
But it is throwing below error, when the data is inserted into the above partitioned table:

````
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
.
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.FSLimitException$PathComponentTooLongException): The maximum path component name limit of hr=%7B%22group%22%7B%22action%22%3A%22Change%22,%22gid%22%22,%22isId%22%3A%22Y%22},%7B%22action%22Add%22,%22gid%111%22,%22isId%%22},%7B%22action%22%3A%22Delete%22,%22gid%2524%22,%22isId%22N%22}%5D} in directory /data/hdfs/tmp/test/.hive-staging_hive_2020-01-04_00-27-05_24_76879687968796-1/-ext-10000/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20200104002705_0027_m_000000_0/dt=N is exceeded: limit=255 length=399
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.verifyMaxComponentLength(FSDirectory.java:1113)
```
````

I notice that the error has few strings which are present in the json data like: group, Change, gid, etc.
Not sure if this is related to the json data being inserted to the col3_json.

Please suggest.

Comment: Your `hr` String is that JSON blob, not `col3_json`

Comment: According to my data, the col3_json should have json data. This is reflected correctly when the same table is unpartitioned with schema as: col1,dt,hr,col2,col3_json. But it is not working when the same table is partitioned.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that your table contains incorrect data. `hr=%7B%22group%22%7B` is saying that one of the hr values starts with the string like `{"group":`. Please show your insert statements

Comment: The issue is resolved. The issue was with the sequence of the data being inserted. The partition column data should have been placed at the end of all columns, but my dataframe didnt have them at the end. Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below if you've found the answer